# memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

ElasticSearch 5.6.7 throws somewhat misleading following error and refuse to start:

```
[2018-08-02T10:07:50,333][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [esm56n3] node validation exception
[2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked
[2]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
```

What are possible causes?

Answer (score 2):

Responding to my own question.
Assuming that all set from [OS limits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/setup-configuration-memory.html#bootstrap-memory_lock) point of view, it could also be that your ***"/tmp"*** containing partition missing ***"exec"*** option. 
You have several options to correct it and start elasticsearch process here:

1. fix your /etc/fstab to remove noexec from /tmp containing partition and run mount -oremount
2. just a run-time fix by enabling exec option: mount -oremount,exec
3. Add the following option to elasticsearch jvm config (jvm.options) to point to partition with exec capabilities:
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/temp/dir

Then go ahead and restart your elasticsearch systemctl daemon (you do not run it on CentOS < 7, do you? :-)
More details [here](https://www.mtbo.tech/2018/08/tmp-no-exec-can-prevent-jvm-backed.html).